# Replace a specific line in a text file

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to write code for Windows that will run an exe call `foil2w.exe`  which makes some aerodynamics calculation from an airfoil. This `exe` has an input text file (`dfile_bl`) with a lot of variables. Then after every run, I have to open it, change a value (the angle of attack) from 0 to 16,  and run it again. Also generates an ouput file called `aerola.dat` where I have to save the last line which is the one which has the results. 
What I'm trying to do is automate the process, run the program, save the results change the angle and run it again. I have done it for Linux and used the `sed` command to find and replace the line with the angle. Now I have to do it for windows and I have no clue how to start. The code I made for Linux, which works fine:

```
import subprocess
import os

input_file = 'dfile_bl'
output_file = 'aerloa.dat'
results_file = 'results.txt'

try:
    os.remove(output_file)
    os.remove(results_file)
except OSError:
    pass

for i in [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]:
    subprocess.call('./exe', shell=True)
    f = open(output_file, 'r').readlines()[-1]
    r = open(results_file, 'a')
    r.write(f)
    r.close()
    subprocess.call('sed -i "s/%s.00       ! ANGL/%s.00       ! ANGL/g" %s' % (i, i+2, input_file), shell=True)

subprocess.call('sed -i "s/18.00       ! ANGL/0.00       ! ANGL/g" %s' % input_file, shell=True)
```

The dfile looks like:

```
3.0          ! IFOIL
n2412aN    
0.00       ! ANGL
1.0        ! UINF 
300        ! NTIMEM
```

EDIT:
Now is working fine

```
import subprocess
import os
import platform

input_file = 'dfile_bl'
output_file = 'aerloa.dat'
results_file = 'results.txt'
OS = platform.system()
if OS == 'Windows':
    exe = 'foil2w.exe'
elif OS == 'Linux':
    exe = './exe'

try:
    os.remove(output_file)
    os.remove(results_file)
except OSError:
    pass

for i in [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]:
    subprocess.call(exe, shell=OS == 'Linux')
    f = open(output_file, 'r').readlines()[-1]
    r = open(results_file, 'a')
    r.write(f)
    r.close()
    s = open(input_file).read()
    s = s.replace('%s.00       ! ANGL' % str(i), '%s.00       ! ANGL' % str(i+2))
    s2 = open(input_file, 'w')
    s2.write(s)
    s2.close()
# Volver el angulo de dfile_bl a 0
s = open(input_file).read()
s = s.replace('%s.00       ! ANGL' % str(i+2), '0.00       ! ANGL')
s2 = open(input_file, 'w')
s2.write(s)
s2.close()
b
```

Comment: Great initiative, automating this!

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn and a somewhat better question than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901383/python-replce-a-specific-line-in-text-file - but still requires clarification from my original comment to be of broader use ;)

Comment: Could you show us an extract of 'dbfile_bl' ? That might help understand what you try to do.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you replace

```
subprocess.call('sed -i "s/%s.00       ! ANGL/%s.00       ! ANGL/g" %s' % (i, i+2, input_file), shell=True)
```

with something like,

```
with open('input_file', 'r') as input_file_o:
    for line in input_file_o.readlines():
        outputline = line.replace('%s.00       ! ANGL' % i, '%s.00       ! ANGL' % i+2)
```

[1] http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Comment: I try you solution and I'm getting this                    `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run2.py", line 20, in <module>
    for line in input_file.readlines():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines' `

Comment: yeah, `input_file` must be file object, I didn't make this code 100% correct, just to give you an idea... i'll edit example to reflect this...

Comment: Thanks, now I'm having an error for concatenate str and int objects, but I think a can solve it now. Thanks a lot

Comment: If the answer helps you, please accept it, so other people know that this question is "solved" with proposed solution.